# Azure Logic App azure_auth - does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows/listCallbackUrl/action'

Tags: permissions, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, azure-rbac

> The client 'clientId' with object id 'objectId' does not have
> authorization to perform action
> 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows/listCallbackUrl/action' over scope
> '/subscriptions/subscriptionId/resourceGroups/resourceGrpName/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/logicAppName'
> or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please
> refresh your credentials.

I'm calling this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows/list-callback-url?tabs=HTTP) from ADF to retrieve the Workflows - List Callback Url so that I can use it to execute the logic app and I get the above error.
The "Logic App Contributor" role has been added to the App registration that I'm using.

I think I'm missing the step to get [the bearer token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows/list-callback-url?tabs=HTTP#security) (azure_auth) to Authorise with.

The documentation is sparse on how to that.
A guide would be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you need to pass bearer token as authorization to get call back url of logic app.** I have reproduced issue from my side and below are steps I followed,

- Register an application in AD and get client id, client secret and tenant id. Follow this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) to register application in AD.
- Once you have required credentials, create a pipeline in ADF as shown below,
  [image]
- Added two set variables in pipeline for getting client id and client secret. You can assign directly or you can get from keyvault as mentioned in [document](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/azure-data-factory-access-microsoft-graph-api-3bbab165eb40).
- Next added a web activity to get token from
  **url**:[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenantid%7D/oauth2/token)

  **Request type:** Post

  **Body:**@concat(concat('tenant=tenant-id&client_id=',variables('clientid'),'&client_secret='),variables('client_secret'),'&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default')

[image]

- Taken another web activity to get call back url of logic app,
  **Url**:https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/testlap01/listCallbackUrl?api-version=2016-06-01

**Request type:** Post

**Body:**{}

**Headers:**@concat('Bearer ',activity('Web1').output.access_token)

[image]

- Debug the pipeline and able to get call back url of logic app,
  [image]